# How can I generate 2 clocks in testbench with systemverilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need 2 clocks running at different frequencies.  I tried:

```
forever
begin
 #5ns clk1=~clk1;
 #4ns clk2=~clk2;
end
```

With this code, `clk2` will generate after `clk1` is done, but they won't generate at the same time.

How can I write the Verilog code to ensure that the two clocks (`clk1` and `clk2`) will generate at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use 2 separate `initial` blocks:

```
module tb;
    bit clk1, clk2;
    initial forever #5ns clk1 = ~clk1;
    initial forever #4ns clk2 = ~clk2;
endmodule
```

Another way is to use a single `initial` block with a `fork`/`join` instead of `begin`/`end`.

Answer (score 1):

Statements within a `begin / end` block are evaluated sequentially.  You need to create two `forever` blocks for them to run in parallel.

```
forever begin
  #5ns clk1 = ~clk1;
end

forever begin
  #4ns clk2 = ~clk2;
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using non-blocking assignment

```
forever
begin
 #5ns clk1 <= ~clk1;
 #4ns clk2 <= ~clk2;
end
```

Comment: I was surprised to find out that this works (inside an `initial` block).  It is clever, but I would not recommend using it because it is not as straightforward as 2 initial blocks or a fork-join.